# Rackspace CloudFiles C# API: How to list files on root 'folder', and how to list (sub)folders within a 'folder'?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rackspace-cloud, cloudfiles

(1) 
I can list the files on a folder this way:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<GetListParameters, string>();
parameters.Add(GetListParameters.Path, "folder1/"); // get items from this specific path 
var containerItemList = connection.GetContainerItemList(Settings.ContainerName, parameters);
```

However, this:

```
parameters.Add(GetListParameters.Path, "/");
```

or this:

```
parameters.Add(GetListParameters.Path, "");
```

does not work.
How can I query the files on the root folder?

(2)
The code above returns the list of files in a folder.
How can I get the list of folders within a folder? I there any parameter I can set to get this list?
*Note: I know that this is a 'flat' file system, similar to Amazon S3. However, both (cloudfiles and S3) provides a way to work with 'folder'. In S3 is easy. In cloudfiles (with the .net API) I could not find how to do this.*

Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has just been fixed with the latest push and closes [issue #51 on github](https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles/issues/51)

Link to [downloadable package](https://github.com/downloads/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles/csharp-cloudfiles-DOTNETv3.5-bin-2.0.0.20.zip)

Hope this helps.